# Is there a way to parse string with format including dynamic references like "today" or "firstDayOfMonth"?

Tags: java, date, parsing, dynamic

I have a method that must parse a string from a user's file. But this date can be dynamic (current day, last month, first day of current year, etc). Of course, I could create my own method with my own formatter to do that but I wonder if it doesn't exist already with a standard format?

Comment: Could you add any examples? How *dynamic* is that date and how does a user's file look?

Comment: Yes, I believe that the answer is that you can create your own method. At least I have heard of no standard solution.

Comment: Actually it's a bdd test. But since the tested program's result can change by date, I need  that my gherkin can get and parse an expression like "today" or "first day of year" to the correct Date object. I Also need that it can do operation on it...
For instance, it the gherkin group contain a thing like "today -1M" it convert it to the june 22th 2019.

Comment: Would doing it the other way around count as cheating? I mean producing the expected string, e.g., “Yesterday”, and comparing with the observed string.